# I want when I press a button to check if edittexts are empty

Tags: java, android

I am making a calculator and I want to press any calculation button and then check if `EditText`s are empty and then display a message within a toast (I already know how to do that). I tried just adding the

```
if(toast) {
}
else {
 (calculations)
}
```

but it only checks when the app starts. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please upload your code ?

Comment: Yah just a minute please cause i am through my phone

Comment: Downvote Not by Me, but can you please upload a proper code that you wrote ?

Comment: JThanks editor that one

Comment: Ok just wait a minute

Comment: @Vigbyor issue resolved xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, create a method that is fired on the click of the button. This is defined in the XML File like this:

```
android:onClick="your_method_name"
```

Inside the method:

```
if(///maybe use a function here- returns true if some are empty... or editText.matches(""){
///toast code here.
}
```

Something like that

Comment: You will need to get your EditTexts into the method. You can declare them at the top of your class - "EditText ///name;" and then initialize in your onCreate() method like normal.

Comment: And then else and put my calculations

Comment: I'll accept your question in 6 minutes cause i won't let me for some reason

Comment: @Kevin van Mierlo... I've not seen the use of an onClickListener for a button before. Is it necessary??? I'm just interested, as I'm quite new to Java/Android :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
calculatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      isEditTextEmpty();
    }
});

private void isEditTextEmpty()
{
    if (editText.matches("")) 
    {
       //show toast
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  before any calculation 



    if(edittext1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    // editText empty
    else 
{
    calculation();
}
```

Comment: But that's pretty much what i need :)

Comment: No else{} should be used as demonstrated above, at least for what you're doing. The bit of code in else{///code} is used when the EditText's are NOT empty, and not any other time. So if they were full, then calculation would be fired, but if empty, it wouldn't :)

Comment: yeah that's what i want to do!

Comment: @Odie "Well that's wrong correct is else{ } calculations " I didn't get this line. Please explain what you want to say. The method "calculation()" is just to represent where the actual code will go. Let me know If I am wrong anywhere.